# Railsのアプリを作成しています。ActiveRecordで、カラムの最小値 → 最大値 で並び替えをする方法を教えてください。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

#### 現在、Railsのアプリを作成しています。以下、costsテーブルの「signカラムの最小値 → 最大値」 で並び替えをしたいのですがどのようにすれば良いでしょうか？

「signカラムの最小値 → 最大値」で並び替えをしたいと思った理由は、RailsのGem cocoonを使用しているのですが、formで登録後、show.html.erbを見ると、formで登録した順番と表示が異なっているからです。

・環境
Rails 4.2.3

・Gem
cocoon
https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon
http://rails.densan-labs.net/form/relation_register_form.html

【subjects/_form.html.erb】内の「明細を追加」ボタンを押すと、パーシャルファイル( _cost_fields.html.erb )の内容が追加されます。

#### signカラム　データ型：string

```
id: 125,
quantity: "1",
product: "商品B",
created_at: Tue, 13 Sep 2016 15:53:42 JST +09:00,
updated_at: Tue, 13 Sep 2016 15:53:42 JST +09:00,
sign: "2",
subject_id: 93

id: 125,
quantity: "3",
product: "商品A",
created_at: Tue, 13 Sep 2016 15:53:42 JST +09:00,
updated_at: Tue, 13 Sep 2016 15:53:42 JST +09:00,
sign: "1",
subject_id: 93

id: 125,
quantity: "5",
product: "商品C",
created_at: Tue, 13 Sep 2016 15:53:42 JST +09:00,
updated_at: Tue, 13 Sep 2016 15:53:42 JST +09:00,
sign: "3",
subject_id: 93
```

#### 並び替え後、viewでは以下の順番で表示したいです(signカラムの最小値→最大値)。

```
id: 125,
quantity: "3",
product: "商品A",
created_at: Tue, 13 Sep 2016 15:53:42 JST +09:00,
updated_at: Tue, 13 Sep 2016 15:53:42 JST +09:00,
sign: "1",
subject_id: 93

id: 125,
quantity: "1",
product: "商品B",
created_at: Tue, 13 Sep 2016 15:53:42 JST +09:00,
updated_at: Tue, 13 Sep 2016 15:53:42 JST +09:00,
sign: "2",
subject_id: 93

id: 125,
quantity: "5",
product: "商品C",
created_at: Tue, 13 Sep 2016 15:53:42 JST +09:00,
updated_at: Tue, 13 Sep 2016 15:53:42 JST +09:00,
sign: "3",
subject_id: 93
```

【subjects_contoroller.rb】

```
class SubjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_subject, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /subjects/1
  # GET /subjects/1.json
  def show
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_subject
      @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
    end

  end

end
```

【subject.rb】

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :costs, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :costs, allow_destroy: true     
end
```

【cost.rb】

```
class Cost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject
end
```

【subjects/_form.html.erb】

```
<%= form_for(@subject) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages! %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="customer_right_space">
        <div class="field form-group">
          <%= f.label :顧客 %><br>
          <%= f.text_field :customer, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Sample㈱' %>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="field form-group">
          <%= f.label :件名 %><br>
          <%= f.text_field :subject, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Sample㈱ SNO.720' %>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
    <%= f.fields_for :costs do |costs_form| %>
      <%= render 'cost_fields', f: costs_form %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="text-center">
      <%= link_to_add_association '明細を追加', f, :costs %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions text-center">
      <%= f.submit '登録', class: 'btn btn-default btn-success visited_white' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

【subjects/_cost_fields.html.erb】 ※ 上記の「明細を追加」ボタンをクリックしたときに追加される内容です。

```
    <div class="nested-fields">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr class="success">
          <th class="text-center">符号</th>
          <th colspan="3" class="text-center">材質・品名</th>
          <th class="text-center">圧力</th>
          <th class="text-center">サイズ</th>
          <th colspan="3" class="text-center">備考</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3" class="vertical_center"><%= f.text_field :sign, class: 'form-control' %></td><!-- 符号 -->
          <td colspan="3" class="field form-group"><%= f.text_area :product, class: 'form-control', placeholder: '商品A' %></td><!-- 材質・品名 -->
          <td class="field form-group"><%= f.text_field :pressure, class: 'form-control' %></td><!-- 圧力 -->
          <td class="field form-group"><%= f.text_field :size, class: 'form-control' %></td><!-- サイズ -->
          <td colspan="3" class="field form-group"><%= f.text_area :remarks, placeholder: "備考", class: 'form-control'  %></td><!-- 備考 -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">数量</th>
          <th class="text-center">HVK</th>
          <th class="text-center">Fujii</th>
          <th class="text-center">Imamoto</th>
          <th class="text-center">原価</th>
          <th class="text-center">原合計</th>
          <th class="text-center">売価</th>
          <th class="text-center">売合計</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="up_area">
          <td class="field form-group"><%= f.text_field :quantity, id: "num01", class: 'form-control num' %></td><!-- 数量 -->
          <td class="field form-group"><%= f.text_field :hvk, id: "num02", class: 'form-control hvk num' %></td><!-- HVK -->
          <td class="field form-group"><%= f.text_field :fujii, id: "num03", class: 'form-control fujii num' %></td><!-- Fujii -->
          <td class="field form-group"><%= f.text_field :imamoto, id: "num04", class: 'form-control imamoto num' %></td><!-- Imamoto -->
          <td class="field form-group"><%= f.text_field :unit_price, id: "ans01", class: 'form-control unit_price' %></td><!-- 原価 -->
          <td class="field form-group"><%= f.text_field :price_total, id: "ans02", class: 'form-control price_total' %></td><!-- 原合計 -->
          <td class="field form-group"><%= f.text_field :selling_price, id: "num05", class: 'form-control selling_price_total num' %></td><!-- 売価 -->
          <td class="field form-group"><%= f.text_field :selling_price_total, id: "ans03", class: 'form-control selling_price_total' %></td><!-- 売合計 -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><%= link_to_remove_association '削除', f, class: 'btn btn-default' %></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

【subjects/show.html.erb】

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <th>符号</th>
   <th>数量</th>
   <th>製品</th>
   <th>圧力</th>
   <th>サイズ</th>
 </tr>

<% @subject.costs.each do |cost| %> 
 <tr>
   <td><%= cost.sign %></td>
   <td><%= cost.quantity %></td>
   <td><%= cost.product %></td>
   <td><%= cost.pressure %></td>
   <td><%= cost.size %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_subject_path(@subject) %>
<%= link_to 'Destroy', @subject, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<%= link_to 'Back', subjects_path %>
```

Answer (score 1):

質問と直接関係はありませんが、適切な場面では`params`を直接使うのでなく`Strong Parameters`を使いましょう。

### 回答

適切なところで`.costs.order(:sign)`して `sign`でソートすれば欲しい並びを得られます。

Viewで`order`を呼ぶことに抵抗がないのであれば
`<% @subject.costs.order(:sign).each do |cost| %>`
で解決するはずです（本来はコントローラ側で適切に呼び出せるようにリファクタした方がよいと思います。また`order`と直接の関係はありませんが、おそらく今のソースだとN+1問題も発生します。）。

`costs.order(:sign)`ではなく、`.includes(:cost).order('costs.sign')`を適切な箇所で呼ぶという案もあると思います（おそらくこちらの方法だとN+1問題も解消しますし、コントローラで`order`が呼べます）。
こちらで試しようがないですが`Subject.find(取得したいID).includes(:cost).order('costs.sign')`といったような形になると思います。

Comment: アドバイス頂きありがとうございます！ 大変参考になりました。m(_ _)m
アドバイス頂いた通り、コントローラ側で制御してみます。